# regex in python to extract number

Tags: python, regex

I want regex for the following test cases so that i can get the proper output:-

Test Cases:

```
Input:

address = "73/75 agedabout 56 years, residing at j,j 59 moil"

Output:
60

address = "12th street t.vial age 46yrs, residing at D.NO 59
Eswaran Koil St"

Output:
46

address = "Room no 43 R.Kesavan aged about 37 years, residing at
D.NO 59 Eswaran Koil St"

Output:
37

address = "Door no 32 R.Kesavan 56yrs, residing at D.NO 59 Eswaran
Koil St"

Output:
56

address = "12-4-67 , R.Kesavan aged about 61, residing at D.NO 59
Eswaran Koil St"

Output:
61

address = "R.Kesavan age63, residing at D.NO 59 Eswaran Koil St"

Output:
63

address = "R.Kesavan aged 9, residing at D.NO 59 Eswaran Koil St"

Output:
9
```

I have tried this `1re.findall(r'aged about(?:\:)? (?P<age>\d+) ', txt)`, but not working for all text cases.Let me know if u find any

Comment: The first input has `agedabout` instead of `aged about`; is that a typo on your part or a variant that needs to be anticipated?

Comment: Based on the test inputs, I think the best approach would be to look for the numerical string that appears after "age" but before "at".

Comment: @BenGrossmann its a variant that needs to be anticipated

Comment: @BenGrossmann for some cases there is no age word also..whatever i am trying is ending up failing one of the test casses

Comment: That's true... I suppose that you could account for those cases by looking for the last number that appears before "yr" or "year" in the event that `age` is not present in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (`txt` is your text from the question) ([regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/irnwSd/2)):

```py
import re

pat = re.compile(r"(\d+)\s*ye?a?rs?|aged?\D*(\d+)")

for a, b in pat.findall(txt):
    age = b if a == "" else a
    print(age)
```

Prints:

```
56
46
37
56
61
63
9
```

Comment: `ye?a?rs?` is a neat trick! Nice answer.

Comment: That ye?a?rs? was great , thankyou